# Ordinal logistic regression (or Beta regression) with a LASSO regularization in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cross-validation, lasso-regression, betareg

I was wondering if someone would know an R package that would allow me to fit an Ordinal Logistic regression with a LASSO regularization or, alternatively, a Beta regression still with the LASSO? And if you also know of a nice tutorial to help me code that in R (with appropriate cross-validation), that would be even better!

**Some context:** My *response variable* is a satisfaction score between 0 and 10 (actually, values lie between 2 and 10) so I can model it with a Beta regression or I can convert its values into ranked categories. My interest is to identify important variables *explaining* this score but as I have too many potential *explanatory variables* (*p* = 12) compared to my sample size (*n* = 105), I need to use a penalized regression method for model selection, hence my interest in the LASSO.

Comment: The lasso certainly "selects" variables by setting some regression coefficients to 0. That doesn't mean is selects the most "important" variables. To investigate this, bootstrap your sample B times and check whether the lasso selects the same "important" variables for each bootstrap sample.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that seems like a clever thing to do indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ordinalNet` package does this. There's a paper with example here:
https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/download/v099i06/1440

Also the `glmnetcr` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnetcr/vignettes/glmnetcr.pdf

Comment: That's just perfect, thank you very much!